# Error indice no valido

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

Saludos estoy trabajando con un codigo en python 3.9 con numpy, opencv, entre otras librerias. no lo voy a colocar todo acá porque es muy largo dejo el fragmento donde me está generando el error.

```
def triangulateGraph(graph,imagesize):
newGraph = graph
n = newGraph.str.shape[0]
X = np.zeros((n,4))
colIms = np.array([imagesize[1], imagesize[0]]).reshape((2, 1))
imsize = colIms.repeat(len(graph.frames), axis=1)
for i in range(n):
    validCamera = np.where(graph.ObsIdx[i] != -1)[0]
    P = np.zeros((3,4,validCamera.shape[0]))
    x= np.zeros((validCamera.shape[0],2))
    cnt=int(1.0)
    #Consigue los puntos en el plano de la camara y la matriz de proyeccion
    **for ind in validCamera:
        x[cnt,:] = newGraph.obsVal[newGraph.ObsIdx[i][ind],:]
        P[:,:,cnt] = np.dot(newGraph.focal,newGraph.mot[:,:,ind])
        cnt+=1**

    X[i,:] = vgg_X_from_xP_nonlin(x,P,imsize,X=None)
allscales = X[:,3].reshape((n, 1))
newGraph.str = X[:,0:3] / np.hstack([allscales,allscales,allscales])
return newGraphe
```

este codigo contiene funciones que son llamadas desde otro codigo, y al llamar esta funcion generar el siguiente error:

```
File "D:\DOCUMENTOS\GitHub\Structure-from-motion-python\main.py", line 104, in <module>
graphList[i] = triangulateGraph(graphList[i],imageSize)
File "D:\DOCUMENTOS\GitHub\Structure-from-motion-python\utils\graph.py", line 84, in triangulateGraph
x[cnt,:] = newGraph.obsVal[newGraph.ObsIdx[i][ind],:]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or 
boolean arrays are valid indices
```

ya probé convirtiendo el indice que está generando el erro en entero y aún persiste el problema. si alguien me puede ayudar a resolverlo se lo agradezco..

Comment: Yo quitaría los asteriscos que pusiste de más en el código. Sólo hacen ruido :)